# How to suffix apostrophe-s, with optional middle name and last name?

Tags: php

I'm trying to display the apostrophe `'s` after the full name for example `Samuel L. Jackson’s` but if the last name or middle name is left out the `'s` is prefixed by a space, for example: `Samuel ’s`. Can some one help me correct this problem?

Thanks

Here is the PHP code.

```
if(!empty($first_name) || !empty($middle_name) || !empty($last_name)) {
    echo = $first_name . ' ' . $middle_name . ' ' . $last_name . ' \'s';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$text = array();
if(!empty($first_name)) {
    $text[] = $first_name;
}
if(!empty($middle_name)) {
    $text[] = $middle_name;
}
if(!empty($last_name)) {
    $text[] = $last_name;
}

if(count($text) > 0) {
    echo implode(' ', $text).'\'s';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo trim($first_name . ' ' . $middle_name . ' ' . $last_name). ' \'s';
```

should do the trick?

One more issue: If you have a first and last name, there will be two spaces in between... is that going to be a problem at some point?

Comment: if there is no middle name, then there will be two spaces between first name and the last name

Comment: @marvin HTML will correct the problem wouldn't it unless there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo trim($first_name . ' ' . $middle_name . ' ' . $last_name) . '\s';
```

trim will get rid of any trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Single Quote ?
You could simply use "'s" no need of escaping.

`echo $first_name.(empty($middle_name) ? '' : $middle_name.' ').$last_name."'s"`

alternative

```
$names = array($first_name);
if(!empty($middle_name))
  $names[] = $middle_name;
$names[] = $last_name;
echo implode(' ', $names)."'s";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$full_name = trim($first_name.' '.$middle_name);

if(!empty($full_name) && !empty($last_name)){
  $full_name .=' '.$last_name."'s";
  echo $full_name;
}
```

Comment: $full_name cannot be blank as $first_name and $last_name can not be blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = ""
if (!empty($first_name)
  $a .= $first_name . " "
if (!empty($middle_name)
  $a .= $middle_name . " "
if (!empty($last_name) 
  $a .= $last_name . " 's"
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo
  (empty($first_name) ? '' : $first_name) .
  (empty($middle_name) ? '' : ' ' . $middle_name) .
  (empty($last_name) ? '' : ' ' . $last_name) . "'s";
```

If the variables will always be set:

```
echo str_replace(
  '  ',
  ' ',
  $first_name . ' ' .
  $middle_name . ' ' .
  $last_name . "'s");
```

To display a proper single quote in HTML, replace the `'` with `&#8217;`, which displays as ’.

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
echo htmlspecialchars($full_name, ENT_QUOTES);
```

will solve the problem